# Word for a certain way to solve issues in Software Development

Tags: word-choice

I wonder if English has word for this. I want to say: "This is [XXX] solution", where [XXX] is an adjective with the following meaning:

Say that we have a software with some architecture, and some problem arises, that was not accounted for when the architecture of the software was designed.

First way to solve this is to make just a fast fix, a workaround for that arised situation, but with no focus on what would be the proper design, what does this issue can bring in general, what does it mean for the whole architecture. This is sometimes referred to as "dirty hack" and it often results in a software which has no clear design.

Second way to solve this is to ask "What does this mean for the architecture?". Then re-consider the whole architecture and design with this new information, and propose a clean solution which doesn't fix just this situation in which it arose, but it is already counting with it in its roots, in its design.

What would be the adjective (a single word, if possible) for the second way to solve the problem?

PS: In Czech, we have the term **"systémové řešení"**, but I don't know if we can translate it to English term like **"systematic solution"**...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for terminology confined to the area of software developing and thus falls outside the domain of standard English usage; Computer Science.SE is the correct place to ask.

Comment: In the domain of software development you're probably just looking at the difference between ***short-term fix / hack*** and ***total rewrite***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers doesn't have to be "total rewrite", more like ***global re-think*** and ***be more conscious about the whole*** kinda thing :-)

Comment: How about Perestroika?

Comment: @ninemileskid ha ha :-))) Funny context esp. for people from former Soviet block... We got sick & tired of this so we could only make fun of it. I am from Czech Rep. :-))

Comment: @Tomas Like the way one gets tired of having to reorganize large chunks of code?

Comment: I would call it a **redesign**.

Comment: @HotLicks 1) "redesign" is not an adjective. 2) there doesn't have to be redesign present. Just that the solution is design-aware.

Comment: @Tomas - But you said "design with this new information".  That sounds like a redesign to me.  (But what do I know -- only worked in software for about 45 years.)

Comment: You’ve made an ***architectural*** change.  It’s an architectural solution

Comment: @HotLicks, no, I said "*re-consider* the design with this new information" :-) At least I meant it this way, perhaps I am missing "the" before the design...

Comment: So you want to *rework* the design.

Comment: I've upvoted the question. I don't agree that with @EdwinAshworth that this needs to be closed or moved to Computer Science.SE. I don't think the question is "outside the domain of  standard English", and it is not particularly *Software Development* focussed anyway. And, to me at least, it seems an interesting question :-)

Comment: You answered it yourself in the question: "a **clean** solution".

Answer (score 0):

The adjective could be **fundamental** given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fundamental) as

> **fundamental**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1.2** So basic as to be hard to alter, resolve, or overcome.
>   *the theories are based on a fundamental error*

It is not *specific* to the software industry (although I do have experience of it).
You could say

> The software needs a **fundamental** rethink / review / redesign.

---

An informal *phrase* might be

> The software needs redesigning **from the ground up**.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/from_the_ground_up) says

> **from the ground up**
>   PHRASE *informal*
>
> Completely or complete.
>   *I had to build the whole navigational structure again from the ground up.*

Comment: thanks Weather. Fundamental is getting close :-) *"From the ground up"* sounds more like you have to throw out everything, which is not the case... you just have to re-think the situation in the context of the whole.

Comment: "From the ground up" does not mean you *have to* throw away everything that was done. Some of the work may be re-usable, either completely, or with some changes, but you would have to work through it all logically.

Comment: Thanks. I think "fundamental" is the closest up to now, but it also has a little different meaning (something which forms the basis, the fundament) so I am still looking for a better word :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first concept could be described as a hack, a kludge, etc. - there are a variety of words which describe methods of production which are regarded as unsuitable for habitual application, or to describe qualities manufactured into a product or machine which make it unsuitable to be used indefinitely into the future.

The second concept you mention could be described as a *reintegration* (if roughly the same elements are present but in slightly modified relations which restores the harmony of the whole).

If there is a desire to emphasise that the conceptual structure is totally new or significantly reworked, people usually resort to intensifiers like "a *complete* redesign*. You might get away with saying "reinvention" or "reimagination", but intuitively I still strongly expect to see the word "complete" prefixed.

The problem with any of these formulations is that people usually recognise that anything which is redone does not jettison all of the old structures and elements, so a total or complete redesign is often a hyperbolic way of describing adjustments which affect many areas of a design.

Also, the Czech notion of a *systematic solution* translates fairly well into English - in context, people would readily understand the difference between a hack and a systematic solution.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I am looking for specific adjective describing the property of the solution. Please see the first paragraph of my answer :-) 

So you think that **systematic solution** could be used?

Comment: @Tomas, certainly, *systematic solution* is a good phase, although it has a slightly euphemistic tenor to my ear. If you have a machine that keeps bursting into flames unexpectedly, for example, then you could say "we have buckets of water on hand, but we need to find a *systematic solution*" (i.e. a solution that prevents the machine bursting into flames, rather than a solution which merely quenches flames as they arise).

Answer (score 0):

In software development lifecycle jargon we would refer to the quick fix as a “patch” and we would refer to the rebuilt permanent solution as an “upgrade” and distinguishes the change as a new version of the software.

You can say it is Software X 1.1 or Software X 2.0. The decimals usually refer to implementation of patches to fix minor bugs. The integer refers to new versions of the software and where one might expect a significant change to the underlying architecture, user interphase or coding methodology.

You may also consider referring this to a “rebuild solution”

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for specific adjective describing the property of the solution. Please see the first paragraph of my answer :-)

Comment: @Tomas an “Upgrade solution”